# Post your already posted question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, old-questions

Suppose you ask a question in SO regarding an issue with appropriate tags to it, but you find out that there are not many people addressing your question and you are still struggling with it. New questions get posted and your question gets trapped under the new ones, unanswered/inconclusive! You get into a chat room related to your post and not find users online. Do you re-post the question?

What are the options that we got in such a case?

Comment: Yep, that duplicate exactly addresses that issue.

Comment: @Emracool Where are my comments? did those get auto-deleted or someone else deleted it? I dont see your comment as well..Whats wrong? 
You seem to be a pro with high reputation thats why thought of asking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, reposting a question is in my opinion not an option. It will be closed as duplicate, so please avoid it. In some cases, you will also surely get many downvotes, so just don't do that.

Sometimes, if I get no answers, I also post my question after a nice *hello guys* into related channels.

But also keep in mind that sometimes you get answers even after a month. Well, not sure if that answer will be helpful to you, but that also happens often.

Also remember to add a full minimal example of your problem, so it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: yes I also believe that reposting is not a solution. thanks!